# Executing a command over SSH with python

Tags: python, ssh

I am trying to execute all multiple commands over SSH with python.

Every time, I get a "unexpected (" error.

Please give the correct syntax for this. Thank you.

```
os.popen('''ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no '''+host+''' 'echo "<td>" $(uname -ri) "</td>"; free | grep "Mem:" | awk '\''{ print "<td>" $2/1024 " MB (" int($4*100/$2) "%) </td>" }'\''; free | grep "Swap:" | awk '\''{ print "<td>" int($3*100/$2) "%" }'\''; echo "</td><td>" $(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "processor" | wc -l) "@" $(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MHz" | sort -u | awk '\''{ print $4 }'\'') "Mhz" $(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cache size" | sort -u | awk '\''{ print "(" $4 " " $5 ")</td>" }'\'')'" ''').read()
```

As of now, I am using:

```
 data1=os.popen('''ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no '''+host+''' 'echo "<td>" $(uname -ri) "</td>";' ''').read().rstrip()
 data2=os.popen('''ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no '''+host+''' free | grep "Mem:" | awk '{print "<td>" $2/1024 " MB("int($4*100/$2)"%)</td>"}' ''').read().rstrip()
 data3=os.popen('''ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no '''+host+''' free | grep "Swap:" | awk '{ print "<td>" int($3*100/$2) "%" }' ''').read().rstrip()
 data4=os.popen('''ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no '''+host+''' cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "processor" | wc -l ''').read().rstrip()
 data5=os.popen('''ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no '''+host+''' cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MHz" | sort -u | awk '{ print $4 }' ''').read().rstrip()
 data6=os.popen('''ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no '''+host+''' cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cache size" | sort -u | awk '{ print "(" $4 " " $5 ")</td>" }' ''').read().rstrip()
```

Comment: your code is very hard to read concerning what is on what escaping/nesting level. some additional newlines and some string formatting ala `"command %s %s" % (param1, param2)` would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best if you use a proper library for doing that. 
Personally I've worked with paramiko and it was pretty straightforward.

Take your pick:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/SecureShell